# Android 4.2.2 : Pause and resume video recording?

Tags: android, video, camera, recording, resume

I just upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S2 from Android 4.1.2 to 4.2.2 (SlimRom).

The new video recording interface does not have pause and resume functions anymore :-(

How could I get them back (without downgrading)?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what else did you expect from a non-offical ROM, but take a look at the official Notes for the Android 4.2.2. :

**Browser and WebView**

> Browser has improved performance, CPU and memory efficiency. With
>   better performance for animations and HTML5 canvases and an updated
>   JavaScript Engine (V8), pages load faster and feel smoother. Browser
>   now has better HTML5 video support, and has a new user experience.
>   **Just touch the video to play and pause**, and smoothly transition into
>   and out of fullscreen mode. Browser now supports the updated HTML5
>   Media Capture specification on input elements. WebView now supports
>   vertical text, including Ruby Text and other vertical text glyphs.

I guess that if that ROM even uses the new stock interface - there are the buttons you're searching for. If not - I didn't find any new changes in the video playback in any of the 4.2.2. builds in the [Changelog](http://www.slimroms.net/index.php/changelog).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @g00dy :) I guess I should stick to the official release of Android 4.2.2 then.

Comment: I guess so .. take care :)